# I need help getting my simple 2D puzzle to work

Tags: java, user-interface, puzzle

The idea is that the permutation puzzle is in the surface of a torus. I set it so that you move the pieces by pressing Q, W, E, D. The problem I have is that when you combine horizontal and vertical moves the numbers (representing colors) overlap. Later I want to have 1 and 2-colors pieces and make it bigger but right now I need to change the code to make it more simple and for it to work right. Any suggestion or comment would help. Thanks.

```
package project;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

//KeyListener is use with keyboard
public class main extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{
    Timer tm = new Timer(1, this); //for animation
    int a1 = 100, b1 = 100; //(a,b) 
    int a2 = 200, b2 = 100;
    int a3 = 300, b3 = 100;
    int a4 = 400, b4 = 100;

    int a5 = 100, b5 = 200;  
    int a6 = 200, b6 = 200;
    int a7 = 300, b7 = 200;
    int a8 = 400, b8 = 200;

    int a9 = 100, b9 = 300;  
    int a10 = 200, b10 = 300;
    int a11 = 300, b11 = 300;
    int a12 = 400, b12 = 300;

    int a13 = 100, b13 = 400;  
    int a14 = 200, b14 = 400;
    int a15 = 300, b15 = 400;
    int a16 = 400, b16 = 400;

    public main()
    {
        tm.start(); //starts timer
        addKeyListener(this); //this refearing to KeyListener
        setFocusable(true); //enable KeyListener
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false); //shift or tab is not use so F
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.black);

        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawString("1", a1, b1);
        g.drawString("1", a2, b2);
        g.drawString("2", a3, b3);
        g.drawString("2", a4, b4);
        g.drawString("1", a5, b5);
        g.drawString("1", a6, b6);
        g.drawString("2", a7, b7);
        g.drawString("2", a8, b8);  
        g.drawString("3", a9, b9);
        g.drawString("3", a10, b10); 
        g.drawString("4", a11, b11);      
        g.drawString("4", a12, b12);   
        g.drawString("3", a13, b13); 
        g.drawString("3", a14, b14); 
        g.drawString("4", a15, b15);      
        g.drawString("4", a16, b16);   
    }    

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) //stops at edges
    {
        if (a1 > 400) {a1 = 100;} 
        if (a2 > 400) {a2 = 200;} 
        if (a3 > 400) {a3 = 100;} 
        if (a4 > 400) {a4 = 200;} 
        if (a5 > 400) {a5 = 100;} 
        if (a6 > 400) {a6 = 200;} 
        if (a7 > 400) {a7 = 100;} 
        if (a8 > 400) {a8 = 200;} 
        if (a9 > 400) {a9 = 100;} 
        if (a10 > 400) {a10 = 200;} 
        if (a11 > 400) {a11 = 100;} 
        if (a12 > 400) {a12 = 200;} 
        if (a13 > 400) {a13 = 100;} 
        if (a14 > 400) {a14 = 200;} 
        if (a15 > 400) {a15 = 100;} 
        if (a16 > 400) {a16 = 200;} 

        if (b1 > 400) {b1 = 100;} 
        if (b2 > 400) {b2 = 100;} 
        if (b3 > 400) {b3 = 100;} 
        if (b4 > 400) {b4 = 100;} 
        if (b5 > 400) {b5 = 200;} 
        if (b6 > 400) {b6 = 200;} 
        if (b7 > 400) {b7 = 200;} 
        if (b8 > 400) {b8 = 200;} 
        if (b9 > 400) {b9 = 100;} 
        if (b10 > 400) {b10 = 100;} 
        if (b11 > 400) {b11 = 100;} 
        if (b12 > 400) {b12 = 100;} 
        if (b13 > 400) {b13 = 200;} 
        if (b14 > 400) {b14 = 200;} 
        if (b15 > 400) {b15 = 200;} 
        if (b16 > 400) {b16 = 200;} 

        repaint(); // repaint rectangle 
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int c = e.getKeyCode(); 

        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_Q)  
        {
            b2 = b2 + 200; //2nd column
            b6 = b6 + 200;
            b10 = b10 + 200;
            b14 = b14 + 200;

            b3 = b3 + 200; //3rd column
            b7 = b7 + 200;
            b11 = b11 + 200;
            b15 = b15 + 200;
        }  
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_W)  
        {
            b1 = b1 + 200; //1st column
            b5 = b5 + 200;
            b9 = b9 + 200;
            b13 = b13 + 200;

            b4 = b4 + 200; //4th column
            b8 = b8 + 200;
            b12 = b12 + 200;
            b16 = b16 + 200;
        }    

        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_E)  
        {
            a1 = a1 + 200; //1st row
            a2 = a2 + 200;
            a3 = a3 + 200;
            a4 = a4 + 200;

            a13 = a13 + 200; //4th row
            a14 = a14 + 200;
            a15 = a15 + 200;
            a16 = a16 + 200;
        }    
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_D)   
        {
            a5 = a5 + 200; //2nd row
            a6 = a6 + 200;
            a7 = a7 + 200;
            a8 = a8 + 200;

            a9 = a9 + 200; //3rd row
            a10 = a10 + 200;
            a11 = a11 + 200;
            a12 = a12 + 200;
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){} //when you stop pressing, vel 

    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        main m = new main();
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setTitle("Torus");
        jf.setSize(800,800);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.add(m);
        jf.setVisible(true); // after adding all components to the JFrame
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Are you sure that you can do an animation with a timer? And what about all those hard-coded pixel-coordinates for drawing? And where is the (object) model for your puzzle? How do you manage state? One advice from me: start from scratch after you have read some tutorials about games. Finally, I thinks `Java Swing` is not the best choice to write a game nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

The real obvious thing here is the bad use of variables ,instead of all these a1 a2 a3..... b1 b2.... maybe just consider using arrays, maybe a two dimensional array instead? From there you could start to make your code a bit better.

Comment: Thank you'll for your feedback.

Comment: I got it to work using import java.awt.Point; and 16 points but I would say it still needs improvement because the code is long.